# Limit User to One session

Tags: php, laravel

I want to limit user to only one session in my Laravel App, I added this method in my login controller. This work

```
public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user){
    $previous_session = $user->session_id;

    if ($previous_session) {
            \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
        }

        Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
        Auth::user()->save();
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

}
}

But when I add,

```
    public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user){
        $previous_session = $user->session_id;

       $user = DB::table('users')->where('role', 'basic')->first();

        if ($user) {

        if ($previous_session) {
                \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
            }

            Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
            Auth::user()->save();
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }
}
}
```

to only apply the method based on user role, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: `$user` isn't a string. It has a property named `role` that would match `basic`

Comment: Please, can you explain better? What I am trying to achieve is to assign the event to the user "Basic".

Comment: Your question said `if($user==='basic')` but the result of a query should be compared as  `if( $user->role === 'basic')`. However, you are also overwriting the `$user ` parameter of the method. I doubt you really need to query the DB if the user already comes in the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using the `AuthenticateSession` middleware.

After the user logs in, call `Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->password)` and it will invalidate other sessions.

Comment: What I want to achieve is invalidate a particular user role.